# How to solve a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Using the below sets of equations, I want to find the expression for `ζ`, `η` and `eg` using Mathematica.

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{\eta} \zeta = g \frac{1-\lambda_{\text{ch}}^2}{1-g^2 \lambda_{\text{ch}}^2} \sqrt{T} \lambda, \hspace{24 mm}\\ \frac{\eta \epsilon^g}{2+\eta \epsilon^g} =g^2 \frac{T \epsilon}{2+T \epsilon},\hspace{36 mm}\\ \frac{\eta\left[\zeta^2\left(2-\epsilon^g\right)+\epsilon^g\right]}{2-\zeta^2\left[2+\eta\left(\epsilon^g-2\right)\right]+\eta \epsilon^g}=g^2 \frac{T\left[\lambda^2(2-\epsilon)+\epsilon\right]}{2-\lambda^2[2+T(\epsilon-2)]+T \epsilon}\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}\lambda_{\text{ch}}^2&=\frac{T\epsilon}{2+T\epsilon}\end{aligned}$$

The above system of equation should be reduced to:
$$
\begin{aligned}\zeta & =\lambda \sqrt{\frac{\left(g^{2}-1\right)(\epsilon-2) T-2}{\left(g^{2}-1\right) \epsilon T-2}},\\ \eta &=\frac{g^{2} T}{\left(g^{2}-1\right) T\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(g^{2}-1\right)(\epsilon-2) \epsilon T-\epsilon+1\right]+1}, \\ \epsilon^{g}&=\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\left(g^{2}-1\right)(2-\epsilon) \epsilon T, \hspace{43 mm}
\end{aligned}$$
Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

**Code:**

```
Solve[Sqrt[η] ζ == g λ Sqrt[T] (1 - λ^2)/(1 - g^2 λ^2) && 
   η eg/(2 + η eg) ==  g^2 T ϵ/(2 + T ϵ) && 
   η (ζ^2 (2 - eg) + eg)/(2 - ζ^2 (2 + η (eg - 2)) + η eg) == 
    g^2 T (λ^2 (2 - ϵ) + ϵ)/(2 - λ^2 (2 + T (ϵ - 2)) + T ϵ), {ζ, η, eg}]
```

Comment: What happens when you run your Solve expression?

Comment: I'm not getting any response, and the process seems to be stuck in a running status

Comment: Check your code, it has typos.

Comment: It was a typo, have corrected it.

Comment: Does the context which gave rise to these equations indicate any constraints on the variables and/or parameters? Are any Positive? NonNegative? Bounded? Using the constraints as assumptions might help.

Comment: Yes, these physical parameters have some constraints: 0 ≤ ζ ≤ 1, 0 ≤ η ≤ 1, eg ≥ 0.

Comment: Are there any constraints on T, g, ∈, or ?  Even if there aren't numerical constraints, do they need to be real numbers, integers, rational numbers, etc.?

Comment: Constraints on the variables: 0 ≤ T ≤ 1, ∈ = 2 * NB / T < 2, g > 1 and  ^2 < 1

Comment: What is NB? Is it the Boltzmann Constant? If so, its value will depend on the units, so I might just substitue a simpler numerical constraint for ∈, namely 0 < ∈ < 2.

Comment: ∈, the excess noise has a simple relation with NB (thermal noise), given by ∈ = 2 * NB / T.  The constraint on excess noise to maintain the effective systems' physicality.  so, we can simply substitute numerical constraint for ∈,  0 < ∈ < 2, Reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0959.pdf, Page-7, APPENDIX A

Comment: Have you verified the target solutions you posted? For instance, I tried substituting `{g -> 3/2, \[Lambda] -> 1/2, \[Epsilon] -> 3/2, T -> 2/3}` (which are all within your stated constraints) into both your and Bob's solutions for ζ.  When I did so, I got 0.898... and 0.959..., respectively, indicating they are not equivalent.  For your posted solution, I used: `\[Zeta] = \[Lambda]*  Sqrt[((g^2 - 1)*(\[Epsilon] - 2)*T - 2)/((g^2 - 1)*\[Epsilon]*T - 2)]`.  Note that Bob did verify his solutions by back-substitution.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. You are absolutely right, there was a mistake in the first equation I posted. It should be:

[Zeta] = -g \frac{\sqrt{T} \lambda}{\sqrt{\eta}} \frac{1 - \lambda_{\text{ch}}^2}{1 - g^2 \lambda_{\text{ch}}^2},

instead of

[Zeta] = g \frac{\sqrt{T} \lambda}{\sqrt{\eta}} \frac{1 - \lambda^2}{1 - g^2 \lambda^2}.

I apologize for the oversight, and I have now updated the equation in the question accordingly. Additionally, I've added one more equation to ensure a consistent set of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply include the constraint condition `cond` and limit it to `Reals`. After that, everything becomes straightforward.

$\lambda_{ch}$ is replaced because it is a intermediate variable, which doesn't appear in the final solution.

P.S. Convert my code to StandardForm would be more readable.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqs = {Sqrt[\[Eta]] \[Zeta] == 
   g \[Lambda] Sqrt[T] (1 - Subscript[\[Lambda], ch]^2)/(
    1 - g^2 Subscript[\[Lambda], ch]^2) ,
     (\[Eta] eg)/(2 + \[Eta] eg) ==  
   g^2 (T \[Epsilon])/(2 + T \[Epsilon]) , 
    ( \[Eta] (\[Zeta]^2 (2 - eg) + eg))/(
   2 - \[Zeta]^2 (2 + \[Eta] (eg - 2)) + \[Eta] eg) == 
   g^2 (T (\[Lambda]^2 (2 - \[Epsilon]) + \[Epsilon]))/(
    2 - \[Lambda]^2 (2 + T (\[Epsilon] - 2)) + T \[Epsilon])};

(* replace lambda_ch *)
eqsf = FullSimplify[
  eqs /. {Subscript[\[Lambda], ch]^2 -> (T \[Epsilon])/(
     2 + T \[Epsilon])}]

cond = {0 <= T <= 1, \[Epsilon] < 2, g > 1, -1 <= \[Lambda] <= 1};

sol=Solve[Join[eqsf , cond], {\[Zeta], \[Eta], eg}, Reals]

FullSimplify[sol]

eqsf /. sol // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Could you add some commentary to explain your approach?

Comment: @Peace Wang: Yes, this is the final expression I was aiming for. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you can do me a favor to accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = Sqrt[η] ζ == g λ Sqrt[T] (1 - λ^2)/(1 - g^2 λ^2);
eq2 = η eg/(2 + η eg) == g^2 T ϵ/(2 + T ϵ);
eq3 = η (ζ^2 (2 - eg) + 
       eg)/(2 - ζ^2 (2 + η (eg - 2)) + η eg) ==
   g^2 T (λ^2 (2 - ϵ) + ϵ)/(2 - λ^2 (2 + T (ϵ - 2)) + T ϵ);
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) the equations in steps

```
solζ = Solve[eq1, ζ][[1]];

solη = Solve[eq2, η][[1]];

eq4 = eq3 /. solζ /. solη // Simplify;

soleg = Solve[eq4, eg][[1]] // FullSimplify;

solη = solη /. soleg // FullSimplify;

solζ = solζ /. solη;

sol = {soleg, solη, solζ} // Flatten

(* {eg -> -((ϵ ((-1 + 
            g^2)^2 T^2 ϵ (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-2 + ϵ) λ^2) - 
         4 (-1 + g^2) T (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-1 + ϵ) λ^2) + 
         4 λ^2 (3 - 
            2 g^2 + (-3 + g^4) λ^2 + λ^4)))/(2 (-2 + (-1 + 
            g^2) T ϵ) λ^2 (-1 + λ^2)^2)), 
 η -> (4 g^2 T λ^2 (-1 + λ^2)^2)/((-1 + 
        g^2)^2 T^2 ϵ (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-2 + ϵ) λ^2) - 
     4 (-1 + g^2) T (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-1 + ϵ) λ^2) + 
     4 λ^2 (3 - 2 g^2 + (-3 + g^4) λ^2 + λ^4)), 
 ζ -> (g Sqrt[T] λ (-1 + λ^2))/(2 (-1 + 
       g^2 λ^2) √((g^2 T λ^2 (-1 + λ^2)^2)/((-1 \
    + g^2)^2 T^2 ϵ (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-2 + ϵ) λ^2) - 
          4 (-1 + g^2) T (-1 + λ^2)^2 (-ϵ + (-1 + ϵ) λ^2) + 
          4 λ^2 (3 - 2 g^2 + (-3 + g^4) λ^2 + λ^4))))} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
{eq1, eq2, eq3} /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: This is not the simplified expressions that I am trying to obtain. Nevertheless, Thank you very much for your valuable contribution and efforts.